# How to compress RAW RGB 10-bit data?

Tags: raw, jpeg, tiff, rgb

This might seem like a general question, however I could not find an answer for. Specifically, I am using a [CMOS image sensor](https://elcodis.com/parts/5811639/OV9630.html) that has the following general capabilities:

- Array Size: 1280 x 1024 (SXGA), can also take 640 x 480 (VGA)
- Output Formats    (10-bit): Raw RGB Data

When I take an SXGA (1280 x 870), i store the file (pragmatically) with a .RAW extension. The file size is about 1000 KB.
When I take a VGA (640 x 480) the size is about 300 KB.

Are they already considered as "compressed"? Is is possible to compress these to a smaller size (both lossless tiff and lossy jpeg maybe)?

So far, I am convinced that the images I am taking don't have a specific format and are considered as [Raw bitmap](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Raw_bitmap). Am I wrong?

References to achieve my goal is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your overall goal?  Will the image data be analysed scientifically or is it solely for display purposes?  As you stated in another comment, transfer time is off the essence in a limited bandwidth environment so you might want to be more clear about that.

Comment: Both. Thus doesn't need to be 100% resolution or definition. I am looking for a good quality with reduced transfer time, I am trying to balance between both.

Comment: Just zip the files.

Comment: Lossless compression of general data is possible via zip and many other routines. The amount of compression possible depends on the entropy present in the data. Since you have additional knowledge: that the data is an image (color?), that may help find a more optimal lossless encoding. Tiff offers zip compression (and possibly others, since it is an open extensible format). jpeg2000 and other formats, offer lossless image compression that may do better than zip

Comment: FWIW, The "raw bitmap" class of files to which your link refers are a different thing from the "RAW" images that are discussed on this site. A single-chip, color image sensor does not record RGB values for every pixel. It records just red for some pixels, just green for some, and just blue for others. A RAW image from a camera contains nothing but those individual, single-color pixel values. The process of converting that to an RGB image is called "demosaicing." I think that the camera that you're using does the demosaicing for you, and then it gives you the RGB image as a "raw bitmap."

Comment: @SolomonSlow I dont think it does the demosaicing because when I convert it to JPEG using MATLAB it appears grey, but when I demosaic then convert it turns colorful

Comment: Oops! I didn't actually read the data sheet. I was going by the fact that you talked about getting images of different sizes from the camera. That often means demosaiced output, but according to the data sheet, even the smaller-sized images from that camera truly are in RAW format.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz What are you using to connect with and pull data from the sensor?  What are you photographing?  What *is* your "goal"?

Comment: @SolomonSlow It's more complex than that. The "red" filters let a little green and blue light through and vice-versa. It's all measured as a single brightness value. The color of the "red" filters is rarely, if ever, the same color as 'Red' in our RGB output devices. Ditto for "G" and "B".

Comment: @xiota technically, I am using a camera that uses a PIC micro-controller and a memory buffer to get the image data from the sensor described above. Then I use UART communication to get the image into my file system through a buffer. My goal is to compress this RAW data so that I can transmit it through air. Does this answer the question ?

Comment: @MichaelC, I had no intention of opening a discussion about the mathematics of demosaicing. I only wanted to call attention to the fact that each pixel of a RAW file has just one value representing one of three possible color values, whereas a more typical color image file has (or can be decoded to yield) three color values per pixel.

Comment: @xiota I am photographing nature, the purpose if for display, No further processing, just viewing.

Comment: @SolomonSlow But the very important point is, raw data has no color values. It only has brightness values. Each "pixel well" records brightness values from a wide range of wavelengths. The wavelengths allowed through each color filter overlap significantly with the wavelengths allowed through the other two filters, just like the wavelengths to which each type of cones in our retinas are sensitive. Since the colors of the filters do not match the colors of our color rendering systems, *all three* values have to be interpolated.

Comment: To say that the "green" filtered pixels record a brightness value only for "green" is fundamentally incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelC, I didn't say that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You said, *" A single-chip, color image sensor does not record RGB values for every pixel. It records just red for some pixels, just green for some, and just blue for others. A RAW image from a camera contains nothing but those individual, single-color pixel values."* That is fundamentally incorrect. Each sensel records a luminance value that includes *some* light from all three bands. But each sensel is most responsive to the light closest to the color of the filter covering it. The color of those filters does not match the wavelengths of light we use in our color reproduction...

Comment: ... systems for each of the emitted "R", "G", and "B" subpixels for each RGB pixel in the output.

Comment: @MichaelC, I'd say, "simplistic" rather than "fundamentally incorrect." I had no intention of opening a discussion about the mathematics of demosaicing. I only wanted to call attention to the structural difference between a RAW image and a "normal" image. I did not want to go into details that would be unlikely to help answer the OP's original question about how to compress RAW data.

Comment: The "structural difference" between raw sensor data and a color image is that the raw data contains only monochromatic luminance values for each sensel. This is fundamentally different from any output form that includes values for multiple colors for each pixel in the resulting image. To infer that raw image data contains *any* color value at a "pixel" level (the measured output from a single sensel on the sensor) is highly misleading and why many do not even begin to understand what information a raw file contains as well as what it does not contain. It takes zero math to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1280 * 1024 * 10 / 8 = 1638400 bytes.
640 * 480 * 10 / 8 = 384000.

Anything smaller than that must be compressed. Specifically, if you see varying file sizes depending on image content, you know that some compression is going on.

But really, if you want to do something with the data, you have to know the image format anyway and if you know how to decode it, you know whether it is compressed or not.

Once you have the decoded image, you can store it in whatever other format you like, be it TIFF or JPEG.

You can, of course, also try to zip the raw files.

Comment: The reason why it needs to be compressed to a smaller size is because once its stored in a RAW file, it must be transmitted through air with a limited bandwidth, all other processing will be done in the receiver part. A smaller size will enable it to transfer in a shorter time where time is of essence in this application. Is there anyways I can compress without decoding ?

Comment: like i said, zip it. (or any other flavour of general-purpose compression algorithm). by definition, you can't apply image specific algorithms without first obtaining an image, ie. decoding.

Comment: You can't zip an image file like you do a text file. It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @ths if you mean by "decode" it as in viewing it, then I am able to decode it to BMP file. You are saying now that its BMP I can compress it to something smaller (like JPEG)? But as a RAW I can only ZIP it correct?

Comment: So we're not talking about a camera raw file, we're talking about data right from an imaging chip. In which case, this doesn't belong on here, it belongs on stack overflow. This is way beyond "photography" & into data processing.

Comment: right. but converting it to a lossy JPEG is not compressing per se; it's altering actual image data.

Comment: I just discovered the function (imwrite) on mathlab takes in an image array just like mine and convert it to JPEG which reduces size. This means that I do not need to ZIP is directly as described. However this is a bit confusing. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html

Comment: @Sarahcartenz Note that converting your raw file to JPEG is a lossy operation, both in the conversion and because JPEG itself uses a lossy compression algorithm. That may or may not be okay for your purpose.

Comment: note that ~300KB raw image for a 640x480 color camera means you also need demosaicing step before the jpeg compression - otherwise you would be compressing grayscale bayer pattern, which is the least sane thing you can do with jpeg

Comment: Quick question, if i use a lossless compression like zip and during transmission some of the data got lost or some bits flipped, can it still be decompressed successfully ?